# In html I want to make the input bar go further than 100%

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, range

In HTML I have this code...

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $value;?>" readonly>
```

What I want is, that if I make the value, for instance, 120; that the bar goes beyond it's limit and shows me 120%. So I want it to go outside the box. I hope you understand the question like this. The php code is for outputting the variable, that already works. It wil also output a 120, but of course the input range slider won't accept that.

I hope you can help me.

-Joost-

Comment: Well, you can set the max value to 120, but the slider can't exceed the maximum value.... That's why the slider exist.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon So I need to create a div that looks identical. I was hoping there was an easy fix.

Comment: Nope, nothing *easy* there. You can get a slider plugin then modify it, but i'm pretty sure no plugin will allow you to go further than its limit.

Comment: breaking the fourth wall